# Good LaTeX editor for beginner on windows 8?

Tags: windows, resume

I am interested in learning how to create documents through LaTeX and was wondering what editors might be good for someone starting out. I currently have windows 8 but am thinking about installing Ubuntu as well. I'm not looking to do too much, just to create a clean, good looking resume. Thanks!

Comment: See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL).

Comment: I recommend downloading texlive. It comes with all the editors and packages you'll need.

Comment: I'd recommend TeXmaker. It comes with internal pdf viewer that, istead of adobe reader or acrobat, allows to compile your document while it is opened in the viewer.

Comment: The previously mentioned texlive (as a latex distribution) and TeXmaker or TeXstudio (as an editor) have the big advantage that they are available for various platforms. So you can keep your familiar setup in case you make the transition to Ubuntu.